# Hiring Company Contact outside of recruiter company which contacted to represent me

Tags: recruitment, ethics, hiring

I have agreed via email to have a recruiting company represent me for a position. The recruiter scheduled the first two interviews with me and the company. Today, the first person at the hiring company contacted me directly to schedule a third interview. I did call the recruiter and let her know, because I have never experienced this before. Has anyone else experienced this? It seems odd to me and I don't want to be unethical.

Comment: Just tell your recruiter that you got the third interview invite from company X (which you already did) then prepare for the interview. I don't see anything strange in particular (and if there is indeed, your recruiter would have let you know, and it shouldn't be anything you need to be worrying about).

Answer (score 1):

This is very normal business practice, for the hiring company to reach out directly to the candidate to organize interview dates and details, especially for second, third, or more interviews.

So long as you keep your recruiter in the loop and up to date, then you are being both professional and ethical and all should be well. The caveat is that the hiring company never asks you to withhold information from your recruiter.

Your recruiter will no doubt have a good agreement in place to protect them should the hiring company try to hire you behind there back. That sort of behavior is getting rarer and rarer, thank goodness. Companies are beginning to see that the cost of litigation, even only so far as settlement, far outweighs the cost of recruitment fees.

All that being said, you clearly have some good ethical spidey senses, so I've no doubt that they will serve you well in your career, best of luck. T